# Check DateTime for null in linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Is where a way to check if DateTime is null in linq expression? I've IEnumeable method where I'm returning data from database

```
return _requestRepository.ExecuteProcReader(
   myRequest,
   new SqlParameter("@userName", user)).Select(items => new Feed
{
   Id = (int)items[0],
   Title = items[1].ToString(),
   Body = items[2].ToString(),
   Link = items[3].ToString(),
   PubDate = (DateTime) items[4]
});
```

And items[4] is a datetime which can be null in database. So, how can check something like

```
if(items[4] is DateTime)
{
   PubDate = (DateTime) items[4]
}
```

Comment: add a `Where()` before your select method like: `Where(p => p.PubDate != null)`, but if your `DateTime` isn't nullable you'll get an exception anyway

Comment: You should really make `PubDate` nullable, an alternative is this: `PubDate = items[4] != null ? (DateTime)items[4] : DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: @GrantWinney it is  'DateTime'

Comment: `DateTime` is value type and cannot be null unless expilictly defined a as `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option would be to declare `PubDate` as nullable inside class `Feed`declaration.

Like this:

```
class Feed {
  public DateTime? PubDate {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

This will expose truth from database into data access layer and shift your null checks one level up.

See: [Nullable types in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use ternary operator here.

```
return _requestRepository.ExecuteProcReader(myRequest,new SqlParameter("@userName", user)).Select(items => new Feed
{
Id = (int)items[0],
Title = items[1].ToString(),
Body = items[2].ToString(),
Link = items[3].ToString(),
PubDate = ((DateTime)items[4]).HasValue ? (DateTime) items[4] : DateTime.Now
//Or any date you want to use
});
```

Comment: `DateTime` has no member called `HasValue`. this won't compile.

Comment: I assume nullable datetime( DateTime?)  is used here. So it might have the HasValue member.

Comment: you are explicitly casting to a non-nullable type, it doesn't matter what the static type is. try typing this into your IDE, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check for **DBNull.Value** when getting data from a database.
Here's what I'll do :

`PubDate = (item[4] == null || item[4] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime)item[4])`

If you have multiple fields that can be NULL in database, you can put it in an extension method as :

```
public static object GetDBValue(this object value, object defaultValue)
{
  return value == null || value == DBNull.Value ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

And call it with :

```
PubDate = (DateTime)date1.GetDBValue(DateTime.Now);
```